# Run shell script on reboot

Tags: linux, cron, systemd, reboot

Tried two methods and neither seem to be working:

`crontab -e`:

`@reboot sleep 60;/home/linuxbox/script.sh`

and created a service in `/etc/systemd/system/script.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=a generic service to run on reboot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/linuxbox/script.sh
Type=simple
User=linuxbox
Group=linuxbox
WorkingDirectory=/home/linuxbox
```

I follow that up with `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Not sure what is going wrong at this point -- any help is appreciated.

Comment: check `sudo journalctl -u script` to see the log of the service.

Comment: `-- No entries --`

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled cron?

You can enable and start it with

```
sudo systemctl enable cron.service
```

Comment: That returns `Unit file crond.service does not exist.`  But when I run `service --status-all` I do get a `[ + ] cron` entry?

Comment: there's no `crond.service`, instead it's called `cron.service` (without the trailing "d"). However, i doubt that cron is not already running on the system, as this would most likely break all kinds of things)

Answer (score 0):

The `ExecStart` command shouldn't be

`/bin/bash /home/linuxbox/script.sh`

but should be

`/bin/bash -c "/home/linuxbox/script.sh"`.

Comment: didn't seem to make a difference. :(

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created your `script.service` unit, you must of course *enable* it:

```
systemctl enable script.service
```

(This might seem obvious, but in qour question you only mention that you run `systemctl daemon-reload` which is not enough)